# How to make java's interpreter understand "Math.pow" as Math.pow?

Tags: java

For my project I'm supposed to create a graphing calculator (graph the graph) in java given a function as the input. I've figured out already a way to properly graph the function. However I cannot think of a way to make the interpreter understand the function. If I'm able to make it so that I can store the meaning of each term of the function, for example the function f(x) = x^2 -1 would need to be understood as Math.pow(x, 2) - 1 , I can proceed from there.

Is there anyway that I can store the meaning of the function as a group of methods knowing that the function can vary.

Comment: Search for `Shunting yard algorithm`. You will have your solution there ;-)

Comment: Java is a **compiled** language (to a byte-code, but it's not a classical interpreted language). There is no `eval`. So you'll have to implement an interpreter. You could potentially to perform some regex and pass it to the built-in Java JavaScript interpreter (I wouldn't expect a passing grade unless you merely use that to *validate* your own solution).

Comment: You will need to build some sort of parser,

Answer (score 1):

if you deal with only polynomials you can store the coefficients in an array, the function you mentioned for example will be { 1, 0, -1} 
`double [] coefficient = {1,0,-1};`

and if you want to substitute with a value of x you can use for loop

```
int function;
int x = 5; 
for(int i = 0; i < coefficient.length(); i++)
    function += coefficient[i]*Math.pow(x, coefficient.length() - i);
```